# Issues with toString and Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, tostring

I have I am having trouble figuring out an issue I have with a toString method. toString () must be changed so that it prints all the relevant information about the Player (and collection of 
Items). Subclasses should overwrite the superclass toString (), but still use the toString () 
from the super class implementation when this reduces code duplication.

How do I go about doing this?

Player class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Player extends Character {

private String name;
private String type;
public static HashMap<String, Item> backpack;
private int maxCarryingCapacity;

/**Constructor
 * Creates a player with health 100, an empty backpack 
 * and max carrying capacity 100
 * 
 * @param nick the players name
 * @param type the players type
 * @param minDamage players minimum damage
 * @param maxDamage players maximum damage
 */
public Player(String name, String type, int minDamage, int maxDamage) {
    super(name, minDamage, maxDamage);
    setName(name);
    setType(type);
    health = 100; 
    gold = 100;
    backpack = new HashMap<String, Item>();
    maxCarryingCapacity = 100;
    setMinDamage(minDamage);
    setMaxDamage(maxDamage);
}

/**
 * Use an item in backpack
 * @param itemName
 * @return true if item is used, and false
 * if there's no item by that name in the backpack
 */
public boolean useItem(String itemName) {
    Item item = findItem(itemName);
    if(item != null) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + item.getAction() + " " + item.getName());
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean equipItem(String itemToEquip) {
    Item item = findItem(itemToEquip);
    if (item != null) {
        this.minDamage = this.minDamage + item.getBonus();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * Adds item to players inventory. An 
 * item can only be bought if the total weight does not 
 * exceed the players carrying capacity 
 * @param item
 * @return true if the item is bought
 */
public boolean addItem(Item item) {
    int totalWeight = totalWeight() + item.getWeight();
    if(totalWeight <= maxCarryingCapacity){
        backpack.put(item.getName(), item);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Find item in backpack
 * 
 * @param name of item
 * @return item, or null if item is not int the backpack
 */
public Item findItem(String itemName) {
    return backpack.get(itemName);
}

/**
 * Removes item from player's backpack and
 * add item value to player's gold
 * 
 * @param name of item to sell
 * @return true if successful
 */
public boolean sellItem(String itemToSell) {
    Item item = findItem(itemToSell);
    if(item != null) {
        gold += item.getValue();
        backpack.remove(item.getName());
        return true;
    }  else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * @return true if the player is alive
 */
public boolean isAlive() {
    if(health > 0 && health <= 100) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
}

/**
 * @return a string with player information
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    String string = "Name: " + name + " Type: " + type + "\n";
    if(isAlive()) {
        string += "Is alive with health: " + health;
    } else {
        string += "Is dead.";
    }
    string += "\n"+ name + "'s backpack contains the following items: \n";

    for(Item item : backpack.values()) {
        string += item;
    }
    return string;
}

/**
 * @return the players type
 */
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

/**Sets the players type
 * Valid types: Mage, Ranger, Warrior, Rogue
 * @param newType
 */
public void setType(String newType) {
    newType = newType.toLowerCase().trim();
    if(newType.equals("mage") || newType.equals("ranger") || newType.equals("warrior") || newType.equals("rogue")){
        this.type = newType;
    } else {
        this.type = "Unspecified";
    }
}

/**
 * @param item
 * @return current carrying weight
 */
private int totalWeight() {
    int tempWeight = 0;
    for(Item itemInBackpack : backpack.values()) {
        tempWeight += itemInBackpack.getWeight();
    }
    return tempWeight;
}

public int attack(Monster currentEnemy) {
    int damage = Utils.random(minDamage, maxDamage+1);
    currentEnemy.changeHealth(-damage);
    return damage;
}
```

}

The Character superclass (abstract class):

```
abstract class Character
{
public String name;
public static int health;
public int gold;
public int minDamage;
public int maxDamage;


public Character(String name, int minDamage, int maxDamage) {
    setName(name);
    health = 100;
    gold = 100;
    setMinDamage(minDamage);
    setMaxDamage(maxDamage);
}

public Character () {

}

/**
 * Changes the character health
 * The health can not be less the 0 or "less than or euqal to" 100.
 * @param healthPoints
 */
public void changeHealth(int healthPoints) {
    int temp = health + healthPoints;
    if(temp > 100) {
        health = 100;
    } else if (temp <= 0) {
        health = 0;
    } else {
        health = temp;
    }
}

    /**
 * @return true if the character is alive
 */
public boolean isDead() {
    if(health > 0 && health <= 100) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}

/**
 * @return the characters name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**Set to Unspecified if the string is empty
 * @param name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = Utils.checkString(name);
}

 /**
 * @return the characters health
 */
public static int getHealth() {
    return health;
}

 /**
 * Get minimum damage
 * @return minimum damage
 */
public int getMinDamage() {
    return minDamage;
}

/**
 * Set minimum damage, if minDamage >= 5, minDamage is otherwise set to 5
 * @param minimum Damage
 */
public void setMinDamage(int minDamage) {
    this.minDamage = minDamage >= 5 ? minDamage : 5;
}

/**
 * Get maximum damage
 * @return maximum damage
 */
public int getMaxDamage() {
    return maxDamage;
}

/**
 * Set maximum damage, if maxDamage <= minDamage, maxDamage is set to minDamage +5
 * @param maximum damage
 */
public void setMaxDamage(int maxDamage) {
    this.maxDamage = maxDamage <= minDamage ? minDamage+5 : maxDamage;
}

/**
 * Get money
 * @return amount of money
 */
public int getGold() {
    return gold;
}

/**
 * Set money
 * @param amount of money
 */
public void setGold(int gold) {
    this.gold = Utils.checkNegativeInt(gold);
 }

}
```

Comment: You are going to return the superclass's toString method + whatever info you need to add from the sublclass all combined as one.

Comment: Q: Exactly what problems did you encounter with "toString()" in your "Player" class?

Comment: You probably should not use the name `Character` as a class name since Java already defines a class in `java.lang` with that name.

Comment: What part of the code is duplicated?  Since you only have one subclass, so far, we can't see any duplication.  So you may need to tell us what part of your `toString()` method you think would be duplicated in other classes.

Comment: I have a monster class aswell, which also uses name and health in the toString method.

Comment: @user3571018 OK, that's going to make it more difficult, since you want the "Type" information inserted between "Name" and "Health".

Comment: Please be specific about what results you're getting and how they differ from the desired results. Also, this is a massive code dump. Try to narrow it down to the [relevant parts. Please read this advice on [ask] and Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule".

Answer (score 3):

In general, given two classes, `A` and `B` and if class `B extends A` then B has all of the properties of `A` plus some of its own. Therefore, when you implement `B`'s `toString()` method, you should do this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   String newStuff = // description of the new variables
   return super.toString() + newStuff;
   // Now describe the elements of B that aren't included in A
}
```

However, your implementation doesn't give a basic `toString()` method for `Character` so calling `super.toString()` is equivalent to calling `Object.toString()`. Therefore you should first implement toString for your `Character` abstract class.

for example, you could do:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + name + "\nHealth: " ... all the attributes
}
```

There is a lot of redundancy in your code though. First of all, both your `Character` class and your `Player` class have the same `name` variable, which goes against the point of inheritance. In fact, you never even use `Player`'s name variable.

also, there is no point in creating getter/setter methods in `Character` if all the variables are declared public anyways. It is better to make them private and use getter/setters though.

Comment: It's much better to make the member fields `private` and use getter and setter methods.

Comment: I agree I was just saying that having both is entirely pointless

Comment: Note that `super.toString();` by itself is pointless.  `super.toString()` returns a `String`, and you really ought to do something with the result instead of throwing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your abstract superclass has `name` and `health`, but not `type` or `backpack`.  (I just noticed, thanks to user2573153's answer, that you also have `name` in your `Player` class; I don't think you want that.)

I think the first thing you want to do is to answer this question: Suppose you create a new subclass, and you don't override `toString()`, and then an object gets printed out.  What would you want to see printed out?

Maybe you want the name and health printed out.  So you can declare this in your abstract `Character` class (which I think shouldn't be called `Character` because `java.lang` already has a `Character`):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String string = "Name: " + name + "\n";
    if(isAlive()) {
        string += "Is alive with health: " + health;
    } else {
        string += "Is dead.";
    }
    return string;
}
```

Then, if you wanted `toString()` in `Player` or `Monster` to add something to the end of that, it would be pretty easy:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String string = super.toString();  // here's where you call the superclass version
    string += "\n Type: " + type; 
    string += "\n"+ name + "'s backpack contains the following items: \n";

    for(Item item : backpack.values()) {
        string += item;
    }
    return string; 
}
```

In your actual code, however, you want the `Type` information inserted in the *middle* of the string that the superclass `toString()` would return.  That makes things tougher.  I can think of two ways to handle it.  One would be to use some string manipulation methods to search for `\n` and insert the "Type" string in there.  But I think it's better to split the string into two methods.  You can put these in your `Character` class:

```
protected String nameString() {
    return "Name: " + name;
}

protected String healthString() {
    if(isAlive()) {
        return "Is alive with health: " + health;
    } else {
        return "Is dead.";
    }
}
```

Now, your `toString()` in `Character` might look like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return nameString() + "\n" + healthString();
}
```

and in `Player`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return nameString() + " Type: " + type + "\n" + healthString();
}
```

and you still get to avoid duplicated code.  (You don't need to say `super.nameString()` because your subclass will automatically inherit it and you don't plan to override it.)

Answer (score 0):

Superclass methods aren't automatically called.  When you override **toString()** in **Player** and you call **toString()** on an instance of **Player** the only code that gets run is **Player**'s **toString()**.

If you want to include the **toString()** of **Character** in your **toString()** of **Player** you need to make that explicit by calling **super.toString()** in **Player**'s **toString()**.

Your **Player** implementation of **toString()** could be amended to include my recommendation as follows:

```
/**
 * @return a string with player information
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
  String string = "Name: " + name + " Type: " + type + "\n";
  if(isAlive()) {
    string += "Is alive with health: " + health;
  } else {
    string += "Is dead.";
  }
  string += "\n"+ name + "'s backpack contains the following items: \n";

  for(Item item : backpack.values()) {
    string += item;
  }
  return super.toString() + string;
}
```

The salient part of this is changing:

```
  return string;
```

To:

```
  return super.toString() + string;
```